# Combining two mysql tables into one row

Tags: mysql, database, join, pivot, window-functions

I'm trying to combine a few tables into a row.

**Team Table**:

```
+----+-------+
| id | team  |
+----+-------+
| 10 | Team1 |
| 11 | Team2 |
| 12 | Team3 |
+----+-------+
```

**Location  Table**:

```
+----+-----------+
| id | location  |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | location1 |
|  2 | location2 |
|  3 | location3 |
+----+-----------+
```

**Stops Table**:

```
+----+---------+-------------+---------------------+
| id | team_id | location_id |      timestamp      |
+----+---------+-------------+---------------------+
|  1 |      10 |           2 | 2019-11-07 15:27:42 |
|  2 |      10 |           3 | 2019-11-07 16:37:52 |
|  3 |      10 |           4 | 2019-11-07 17:47:62 |
+----+---------+-------------+---------------------+
```

Looking to create the desired table:

```
+----+---------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | team_id |     (loc id=2)      |     (loc id=3)      |     (loc id=4)      |
+----+---------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |      10 | 2019-11-07 15:27:42 | 2019-11-07 16:37:52 | 2019-11-07 17:47:62 |
|  2 |      11 |                     |                     |                     |
|  3 |      12 |                     |                     |                     |
+----+---------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

There will always be a finite number of locations.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated! I've tried a handful of LEFT JOINS, but am not getting far.

Comment: Please show what you've tried, and explain why they are not far enough.

Comment: You should add more information, what happens if there's more than two entries in the stops table for a given team and a given location? Do you want to most recent stop? The last stop? All the stops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do conditional aggregation:

```
select
    t.id team_id
    max(case when s.location_id = 2 then timestamp end) loc_id_2,
    max(case when s.location_id = 3 then timestamp end) loc_id_3,
    max(case when s.location_id = 4 then timestamp end) loc_id_4
from 
    team t
    left join stops s on s.team_id = t.id
group by t.id
```

If you want to generate an `id` column on the fly for the generated results (which makes little sense since you get one record per `team_id` already), then you can use `row_number()` (availble in MySQL 8.0 onwards):

```
select 
    row_number() over(order by t.id) id,
    t.*
from (  
    select
        t.id team_id,
        max(case when s.location_id = 2 then timestamp end) loc_id_2,
        max(case when s.location_id = 3 then timestamp end) loc_id_3,
        max(case when s.location_id = 4 then timestamp end) loc_id_4
    from 
        team t
        left join stops s on s.team_id = t.id
    group by t.id
) t
```

Comment: Thanks so much GMB! This helped immensely! Was completely unaware of CASE within SQL!

Comment: Welcome @TCConway!